# Autoit does't declare the full path in file manager

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to use autoit in python 3.7.4/Win10, but i'm not getting what i want.

In the *autoit.control_set_text* i declare the full path to my file, but when the file manager pops up, it just writes the filename and extension.

What am i doing wrong ?

```
handle = "[CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Open]"
autoit.win_wait(handle, 60)
autoit.control_set_text(handle, "Edit1", r"C:\codigos\TCBot\LastIdeaCropped.png")
autoit.control_click(handle, "Button1")
```

[What autoit writes in the file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYckt.png)

Comment: Autoit = PyAutoIt